# Get string of calling variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Assume I have a variable call like this one

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = new Bar();
foo.bar.property // something

class Bar  { property { get; set; } }
class Foo { Bar bar {get; set; }}
```

is there a way to stringify this call, like

```
string myCall = myStringify(foo.bar.property);
// yields either "bar.property" or "foo.bar.property"
```

Why this? I use reflection to create keys for this. So the above example would create a key "bar.property" in a list (which will go into a database etc.). I could simply write `string key = "bar.property"` but then I wouldn't know if that really existed. Using the above example I could guarantee, that that key actually existed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I added an explanation

Comment: Not quite following, but the `nameof` operator might help. For example, if you have `class C { int B {get; set;}}`, then `nameof(C)` is `"C"` and `nameof(C.B)` is `"B"`. And it works at compile time, so those strings are `const`

Comment: Yes, but `nameof(a.b.c)` gives me only `"c"` and not the rest. How do I get the rest?

Comment: Well, `nameof(a)` will give you the `"a"` and `nameof(a.b)` will give you the `"b"`. So, `nameof(a)+"."+nameof(a.b)+"."+nameof(a.b.c)` will give you the whole thing. And, that's a compile time expression, so it's `const`. And, if you refactor/rename one of the names, the name of expressions will change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are being down-voted, anyway, I came up with this, give it a try.

```cs
static string Stringify<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var memberNames = new Stack<string>();

    var propertyExpression = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    while (propertyExpression != null)
    {
        memberNames.Push(propertyExpression.Member.Name);

        propertyExpression = propertyExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;
    }

    return string.Join('.', memberNames);
}
```

Used like this:

```cs
string yourCall = Stringify(() => f.Bar.Property);
```

Comment: Using `nameof` happens at compile time and yields a `const` string expression. Your solution is all runtime based (and requires digging into the guts of an Expression)